# how to convert php 5.4 to php 8

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website which is based on PHP 5.4 & I want to convert it to PHP 8, This is first time I have got such a task so I have "ZERO" idea how to do it so can anyone please share me any tutorial or a guide how can I do it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's no simple answer to this. Build a PHP test environment; set up your application; run it; fix the problems. There might be many, or there might only be a few. Then test. And test. And test again.

Comment: When I had to upgrade a PHP 5.3 project to PHP 7.1 a few years ago, I started by loading the project into the JetBrains PhpStorm IDE. That IDE product has a feature to analyze the PHP code for the whole project and try to notify you of code that may be deprecated or work differently in the newer version of PHP. It didn't account for 100% of the problems, but it focused my attention on most of them. It saved me many hours of testing. Totally worth it. I agree the remaining problems only take very careful testing. It's painstaking work.

Comment: Along with what everyone else said, you might want to upgrade to 7.4 first, because things were deprecated in 7.x and removed from 8.x, and you want to see those deprecation messages.

Comment: There is also official documentation for upgrading between versions, start at the lowest you can find: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.php

Comment: Another potential issue is the basis of the current project.  Was it based on any sort of framework?  If so, you not only have the issue of updating related to PHP changes and deprecations, but you also have to handle corresponding updates to the underlying framework.   If it is framework based, then in my experience the best solution is to create a new framework project and port the mvc code.

Answer (score 5):

It can be useful and save many hours to scan the errors and warnings with [PHPCompatibility](https://github.com/PHPCompatibility/PHPCompatibility)

This tool analyse your code source and generate a detailed report with warnings and errors for each php file.

If you use docker you can simply run the command below from your project root dir :

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/app" vfac/php7compatibility 8.0 --extensions=php .
```

Comment: +1 for link to PHPCompatibility.  Looks like a nice project.  Spinning up a quick docker container looks like a great tool for taking on this type of task.